# Using MediaWiki ClientLogin For Sign In Verification

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

So we have a long established MediaWiki installation with a pretty big user base. We are now trying to develop a small PHP-based application, unrelated to the wiki (that will live on the same server but not exist within the MediaWiki installation), that we want to implement SSO for. Basically the users of the wiki should be able to use their MediaWiki login to sign into this new application. I prefer to NOT give the new app access to the MediaWiki database directly if possible, so I have been reading up in the API ClientLogin. At the moment I have been using their "API Sandbox" built into MediaWiki to test some basic functions and calls. When I run a test URL, for example:

`http://127.0.0.1/wiki/api.php?action=clientlogin&username=example&password=12345678&logintoken=1234567&loginreturnurl=http://123.com`

I get return status fail, stating "the supplied credentials could not be authenticated." "Authmanager-authn-no-primary". I'm kinda lost as to what MediaWiki is asking for. I will admit, MediaWiki is not something I'm well versed in on the development side, and a lot of what I can find documentation wise to accomplish what I am looking to do is from pre 1.27 versions, where login management was handled differently. Am I going down the right path here, or would direct database connection be smarter? Or is there another whole method that makes even more sense?

Comment: Are you sure it is `logintokin` and not `logintoken`?

Comment: MediaWiki has a modular login system. Maybe there is a module that expects a password. Maybe there is a module that will redirect you to google.com for an OAuth login. Maybe a module will determine you are using a trusted internal IP address, and you don't need to provide anything other than your username. *the supplied credentials could not be authenticated* means none of the modules configured for that wiki found the provided information relevant. When you get that error after providing a username and password, that usually means the password module has been disabled or made optional.

Comment: The relevant configuration setting is [`$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig). You can check the `action=query&meta=authmanagerinfo&amirequestsfor=login` API endpoint to see what kind of fields are any modules listening to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, depending on what exactly you are after and what your requirements are. If you want proper SSO (**single** sign-on), asking the user for their password again doesn't really cut it. If you want to connect a less secure website to a more secure MediaWiki installation, having the passwords go through the less secure site is again not a great idea. OTOH it is fairly simple in most cases - but note that the clientlogin API replicates the login experience. If the user gets needs to provide extra information during login (e.g. they need to change their password because it is too simple), the same information needs to be provided to the clientlogin API as well. (The login API is slightly simpler to use but only works for the basic username+password workflow.)

A direct DB request is possible but messy - you'll have to replicate the exact password hashing MediaWiki does, which might change without warning, you might need to duplicate site secrets, DB credentials etc. Plus it makes an exploit of the other website even easier to convert into an exploit of the wiki. You are very likely going to be better off using the API.

You could check whether the user is logged in on the wiki, via the userinfo API (if the other website is less secure, this is again a bad idea, but also fairly simple). You could set up the wiki as an identity provider, e.g. install the [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth) extension, and use OAuth login (which is not simple, but there are plenty of libraries).

Comment: After doing a bunch of reading, I think that the OAuth direction is probably the smartest. It has some great access control (in my case, I'm simply looking to use the existing userbase, and there are options for authenticate vs authorize). I really did NOT want to get into direct DB access, I'd rather compartmentalize each service so that if a security hole is found in 1 service, it doesn't (or less likely to) affect everything. Thank you for pushing me in this direction!

Answer (score 1):

Or may be change the way you see the issue :

- Is that possible to migrate your current wiki user database to a third party software, and link both of your wiki and new app to this third party ?
- As @Tgr mentioned it, MediaWiki is pretty flexible with login backends. It should not be too hard to find a nice setup (LDAP ? )
- Bonus : this approach can provides you a much more solid ground to build a SSO system.

For the migration, or you replicate your database and the hash mechanism, without duplicating it as Tgr also nicely mentioned disadvantages. Or you steward your users to create a new account on the new system, allowing them to temporary login with both backends.